# Create a function in javascript to receive a JSON parameter

Tags: javascript, html, json, function

I have to create a function that receives a parameter that will be a JSON with the settings for creating a form. This function must then be generic to process any JSON that is sent to it that respects the mapping fields.

The JSON file:

```
var user = {
                "name": "alunos",
                "method": "get",
                "action": "ok.html",
                "autocomplete": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "element": "input",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": " ",
                        "name": "nome",
                        "placeholder": "Digite seu nome"
                    },
                    {
                        "element": "input",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "",
                        "name": "email",
                        "placeholder": "Digite seu e-mail:"
                    },
                    {
                        "element": "select",
                        "name": "gender",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "element": "option",
                                "value": "F",
                                "innerhtml": "Feminino"
                            },
                            {
                                "element": "option",
                                "value": "M",
                                "innerhtml": "Masculino"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "element": "input",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "Enviar",
                        "name": "enviar"
                    }
                ]
          }
```

I have to build the HTML file to create the form, but I have doubts in the JavaScript logic to be able to abstract the information from this JSON file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
         <title>Basico json</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="users">
           <form name="alunos" action="ok.html" method="get" autocomplete="true">

              <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" value=" "></input>        
    
          </form>
       </div>  
      <script type="text/javascript">
          user_update = function () {
                  var formJ = document.createElement("user");

          if(user.name){
               formJ.setAttribute("name",formJ.name)
          }

      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: _"JSON is a textual, language-independent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML"_ - So there's not _"a JSON"_. `user` is an object.

Comment: [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is supposed to create HTML elements and not some arbitrary "user"s